# Unable To Set Container Permissions with SAS Token

Tags: powershell, azure-keyvault

I’m unable to set the storage container permissions when I use SAS tokens. It works fine with storage account keys. Am I missing some permissions in SAS definition?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageSasDefinition -VaultName <vaultname> -Name writesas -AccountName <accountname> | fl *

Parameter      : {validityPeriod, signedPermissions, signedServices, signedResourceTypes...}
ParameterTable : Name                 Value
             validityPeriod       PT30M
             signedPermissions    rwdlacup
             signedServices       bqft
             signedResourceTypes  sco
             signedVersion        2016-05-31
             sasType              account


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $SasToken = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName <vaultName> -SecretName <secretName>).SecretValueText
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName <storageAccountName> -SasToken $SasToken -Protocol Https

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $context -Container  <containerName> | Set-AzureStorageContainerAcl -Permission Blob -PassThru
Set-AzureStorageContainerAcl : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. HTTP Status Code: 403 - HTTP Error Message: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
At line:1 char:66
+ ... ner content | Set-AzureStorageContainerAcl -Permission Blob -PassThru
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureStorageContainerAcl], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Cmdlet.SetAzureStorageContainer
   AclCommand
```

Via Storage Account Keys

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $SAK = "storage account key"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName <accountName>  -Protocol Https -StorageAccountKey $SAK

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $context -Container <containerName> | Set-AzureStorageContainerAcl -Permission Blob -PassThru




 Blob End Point: https://<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/


Name                 PublicAccess         LastModified
----                 ------------         ------------
<name>              Blob                 11/6/2018 12:45:48 AM +00:00
```

Comment: Could you provide your sas token?Just hide the sensitive part, I want to see its format.

Comment: ?sv=2016-05-31&ss=bqft&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2018-11-10T22:34:02Z&spr=https

Answer (score 0):

Has this ever worked? Meaning were you able to set container permissions via the same commands previously. If the answer is no I'll provide you instructions on how to do this via CLI. If yes, please try to upgrade your powershell version

Comment: Actually, We need to get this to work with .net api's. Our application uses the following api to set the permissions on the container and started failing when I switched from using Storage account keys to SAS tokens.

                    _blobContainer.BeginSetPermissions(permissions, null, null),

We see the same behavior with PSCmdlets. The same cmdlets are working with Storage account keys. Makes me think some permissions are missing for SAS token